# Searching JSON document in monogDB for value across array elements

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have some complex document (being new to mongodb schemas, I think it's complext)  that I'm trying to process through for a specific array value match across different array sections of the document.

Sample content of my document:

```
    {  
"_id" : ObjectId("541c0c9bdfecb53368e12ef0"),  
"SRVIP" : "10.10.10.10",  
"INSNME" : "myinstance",  
"DBNAME" : "mydbname",  
"DBGRPL" : [{  
        "GRPNME" : "grp1",  
        "GRPPRV" : "7",  
        "GRPAUT" : [ “AUTH1”,”AUTH2”],  
        "GRPUSR" : [    "USER1",”USER2”]  
    }  
],  
"SAUTLV" : [    { "SAUNME" : "USER4",  
           "SAUPRV" : "0",  
           "SAUAUT" : [ “AUTH2”,”AUTH3”],  
            "SAUUSR" : [ "USER2" ]  
    }  
],  
"USRLVL" : [  
{ "ULVNME" : "USER1",  
              "ULVPRV" : "0",  
              "ULVAUT" : [ "AUTH1","AUTH2","AUTH3"]  
        },  
        {  
    "ULVNME" : "USER2",  
            "ULVPRV" : "2411",  
            "ULVAUT" : [ "AUTH3"]  
        }  
    ]  
}
```

I'm trying to only return the section of the document where for example USER1 exists
At the moment, I've create two different aggregated statement to retrieve the information, but I'm looking at a single statement to search all arrays in the document.

```
Retrieving USER1 statement on DBGRPL array level : 

var var1=[“USER1”]
db.authinfo.aggregate({$unwind:"$DBGRPL"},{$match:{"DBGRPL.GRPUSR":{$in:var1}}},{$project:{SRVIP:1,DBNAME:1,"DBGRPL":1}})

var var1=”USER1”
Retrieving USER1 statement on USRLVL array level:
db.authinfo.aggregate({$unwind:"$USRLVL"},{$match:{"USRLVL.ULVNME":var1}},{$project:{SRVIP:1,DBNAME:1,"USRLVL":1}})
```

The obvious error with the above approach is using 2 different variable type for the queries to work, which is also something I can't resolve at the moment ….

How can I combine the search into a single statement ?

expected output :

```
{  
"_id" : ObjectId("541c0c9bdfecb53368e12ef0"),  
"SRVIP" : "10.10.10.10",  
"INSNME" : "myinstance",  
"DBNAME" : "mydbname",  
"DBGRPL" : [{  
        "GRPNME" : "grp1",  
        "GRPPRV" : "7",  
        "GRPAUT" : [ “AUTH1”,”AUTH2”],  
        "GRPUSR" : [    "USER1",”USER2”]  
    }  
],  
"USRLVL" : [  
{ "ULVNME" : "USER1",  
              "ULVPRV" : "0",  
              "ULVAUT" : [ "AUTH1","AUTH2","AUTH3"]  
        }  
        {  
    ]  
}
```

when searching for USER1.

I will also search across the GRPAUTH, SAUAUT and ULVAUTH sections of the document where say AUTH1 is a value ...

Comment: Can you show us the expected output?

Comment: I've added expected output with additional potential search requirements. Appreciate any suggestions how to code search statement for what I'm trying to achieve. Thx